# How to return a type from an anonymous method/delegate

Tags: c#, lambda

i want to return a string value from an anonymous method/delegate.  How can i achieve something like this: Note this will give a compile time error: Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("aaa");
            sb.Replace("aaa", delegate()
            {
                return "bbb";
            });
```

I' am also trying to create an extension method so i can write code like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("aaa");
sb.Replace("aaa", () =>                
{
  return "bbb";
});
```

What would the signiture of the extension method be?

EDIT:

We have a large internal class which generates tedious xml files.  We want to make the method more readable, more than anything else.  So we want to go 
from:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_repository.GetGenericXml1Template());
sb.Replace("$Placeholder", GetXml1Helper());

private void string GetXml1Helper()
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_repository.GetGenericXml2Template());
   sb.replace("$Var1", DB.Var1);
   ....
   return  sb.ToString();
}
```

So rather than having dozens of helper methods doing slightly similar things we want to at least make the code more readble.

To:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_repository.GetGenericXml1Template());
sb.Replace("$Placeholder", () =>
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_repository.GetGenericXml2Template());
   sb.replace("$Var1", DB.Var1);
   ....
   return  sb.ToString();
}
);
```

Comment: Signature would be Func<String>, but why would you want to do something like that? I am sure there is a better solution to whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Wololo, did u check my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note this will give a compile time error: Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Your delegate is fine – the error just says that it cannot be used here because `Replace` expects a `string` as the second argument.

> What would the signiture of the extension method be?

Well, something like this:

```
static void Replace(this StringBuilder sb, Func<string> f);
```

– but why would you want this? What use-case does it fulfill?

Comment: We have a large class creates xml on the fly. Our xml files are deeply nested, so instead of creating dozens of little helper methods i thought i try with anonymous method to make it read alot better.  The delegates will represent another nested xml level.  The replace methods are replacing $Placeholders in the xml template file with values from the db

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `StringBuilder.Replace` you may want to look into `Regex.Replace`. That way you can do somthing like:

```
Regex.Replace("Input string", "aaa", match => "bbb");
```

Very similar to what you want to do, just out the box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use extension method to achive the expected..

since the default StringBuilder.replace doesnt accept Func<>, you have to create the extension method replace which meets your requirement

here the sample code.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
          public static StringBuilder  replace(this StringBuilder Sb1,string input, 
          Func<string> anonymos)
          {
               return Sb1.Replace(input, anonymos.Invoke());
          }
}
```

and you have to invoke the extension replace method like this

```
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
        s1.Append("hai");
        s1.replace("hai", () =>
        {
            return "bb";
        });
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax to return a string form an anonymous method.
Your problem is different - you're trying to pass an anonymous method to `StringBuilder.Replace()` as the second argument, where it expects a string.

Why are you doing this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to extend the existing method.

Kindly refer to this link --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Func<string> func = delegate()
{
    return "HELLO";
};
sb.Replace("", func());
```

Although I don't see the use of this...

Comment: You are missing the point, he wants to create an extension method that allows this, his anonymous method was fine.

Comment: Well, he wrote that he wanted to create an "extension method too", so I thought that was just some kind of second question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear how you're going to use this - since the example you've posted is trivial, I have to ask ts there any particular reason it needs to be an anonymous method? Couldn't it just be a regular instance method instead?